# Middle 3 letters of word / Python

Tags: python

The task is to print 3 letters from word, for example, from word "python" = tho, from "linebreak" = ebr. If number of letters are even,then the selection window is shifted to the closest letter. (to the left ->)

x = str(input("Enter a string: ")

print(x[2:5])

What I need to do next?

Thank You!

Comment: 1) count the index of the center, 2) `print(x[center-1:center+2])`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, this looks like a homework question, please check the FAQ about [how do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: The indices cannot be fixed like `x[2:5]` to solve the general case. Check if the length is even/odd then find the middle index and then -1 and +1 index.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your question:

```
def middle_three(string):
    lower = (len(string) - 3) // 2 + 1 - len(string) % 2
    upper = (len(string) + 3) // 2 + 1 - len(string) % 2
    return string[lower:upper]
```

Answer (score 0):

As function:

```
def mid(s):
    return s[int(len(s)/2) - 1:int(len(s)/2) + 2]
```

Or as lambda function which look shorter:

```
mid = lambda s: s[int(len(s)/2) - 1:int(len(s)/2) + 2]
```

Usage:

```
>>> mid('python')
'tho'
```

Or without a function:

```
>>> s = input("Enter a string: ")
Enter a string: python
>>> print(s[int(len(s)/2) - 1:int(len(s)/2) + 2])
tho
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if it is possible to write it without def and return functions, just with input, print and len functions?

Comment: @noteikti yes, it is possible. Just assign result of the input to the `s` variable and use the construction witch I posted

Answer (score 0):

I've created extra variable `length` - it's additional.

```
text = input()
length = len(text)
center = int(length / 2)
print("3 middle letters: ", text[center-1:center+2])
```

The last line uses @bereal solution.